# Extract svg path with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to extract the SVG path using regex and javascript, but it doesn't work.

My SVG file :

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100" height="100" viewbox="0 0 100 100">
  <path d="M0.675,11.333h98.849v21.182H0.675V11.333z M0.675,39.576h98.849v21.183H0.675V39.576z M0.675,67.818h98.849v21.184H0.675
       V67.818z"/>
</svg>
```

My regex : `/^<path(.*)\/>$/gm`

I'd like to get this : `<path d="M0.675,11.333h98.849v21.182H0.675V11.333z M0.675,39.576h98.849v21.183H0.675V39.576z M0.675,67.818h98.849v21.184H0.675
           V67.818z"/>`

And I get no results...

Comment: Why aren't `getElementsByTagName` and `getAttribute()` not good?

Comment: Try without `^` and `$`.

Comment: [`<path\s+d="([^"]+)"`](https://regex101.com/r/dT3mL9/1)

Comment: [`<path((?:.|\n)*?)\/>`](https://regex101.com/r/oG6qY1/2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dot in js regex won't match line breaks.

```js
var s = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100" height="100" viewbox="0 0 100 100">\n<path d="M0.675,11.333h98.849v21.182H0.675V11.333z M0.675,39.576h98.849v21.183H0.675V39.576z M0.675,67.818h98.849v21.184H0.675\nV67.818z"/>\n</svg>';
alert(s.match(/<path\b([\s\S]*?)\/>/g))
```

`[\s\S]*` matches any character including line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

Easy!

```
/^<path(.*?)\/>$/gs
```

### Explanation:

1. `s` flag for multiline text. Use it instead of `m` flag which consider each line as **different** string.
2. `.*?` for **non-greedy** regex

Comment: is there `s` flag in JS?

Comment: No. Sorry, should have checked first.